# How to render specific view after clicking specific button. PHP HTML JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I am making a page with soccer teams and leauges. Now i`m printing all Leagues that i want from the database.

```
League 1
League 2
League 3
etc.
```

As you can see each League has its own League_ID. In Database i also have a table of all teams, and each team has matched League (with League_ID). I also have a view, where i can print table of League that i want. This function in php looks like this.

```
public function leauge_table(){
    $tables = $this->scoreTableRepository
                    ->getScoreTable(1); 
    //TODO how to change this "1" static to generated
    //TODO when pressing link
    return $this->render('leauge_table', ['table' => $tables]);
```

And as you can see, when i go to this page i will always see the score table from leauge that has id=1.

And the question is how can i make that when i press for example at "League 2" i will open page but with table matching to League_ID = 2. Shall it be `<button></button>` or `<a></a>` in HTML. And how to pass there League_ID so my php back will see which table should render.
Thank you really for help.

PS
Or maybe do i have to make a seperate view for each leauge score table? And then just simply make buttons direct to these views with simple JS code. But would like to avoid it if it`s possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a link or a button. A link with the league ID as a parameter in the URL is the simplest approach though, if you're new to the concept. e.g.

```
<a href="showleague.php?id=1">League 1</a>
```

The ID would then be available in the php script via `$_GET["id]`, once the link is clicked.

Comment: And where should i read this variable? I got LeaugeController.php where i call "leagues" function that displays list of leagues. How should this function to catch and then render view i want to look alike?

Comment: You should read it in whatever file is mentioned in your link. So in my example the link takes you to `showleague.php`...so that would be where you can write code to read that variable. Obviously it's up to you what filename you want to use in the link.

Answer (score 1):

In your SoccerTeam page add a button in a form with the following :

```
<form action="youpage.php" method="post">
<input name="leagueId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $leagueId;?>" >
</form>
```

And in order to process that information, since we passed an id, we can retrieve it with `$_POST['leagueId']` and because it's a POST request it wont be visible in the url:

```
$leagueId = $_POST['leagueId'];
```